# Проверка пользователя

Tags: php

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if (!session_is_registered(username)) {
      header("location:index.html");
  }
  if ($_SESSION['auth']) {
      // показываем страницу
  } else {
      echo "На сайт!";
?>
```

Проверяем, вошел ли пользователь на сайт. Но мне выбрасывает ошибку. Что делать?

Comment: Влад, тебя яваскриптом!!! Для кого я писал: http://hashcode.ru/questions/32656/как-закрыть-не-зарегистрированному-пользователю-страницу ?  
Что за ошибку выдает?

Comment: Больше не буду =)

Comment: что не будешь? Ошибка какая?

Comment: @Sh4dow, ты пророк, предсказатель и гуру. ООООО!!! *кланяется по-плебейски* они и правда ни фига не читают.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (!session_is_registered(username)) {
```

Заменяем на

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
```

В любом случае,

```
<?php
  session_start();
```

должно быть самой первой строкой, самого главного файла, перед этим не должно стоять ни единого символа, даже пробелов, а

```
 } else {
      echo "На сайт!";
```

Надо, по правилам хорошего тона, закрывать:

```
 } else {
      echo "На сайт!";
  }
```

Влад, еще раз напишешь фигню - начну минусовать и жаловаться.

Comment: Понял!

Comment: Заметь, я не против твоих вопросов. Они забавные и поднимают настроение. Но только если они конкретные, пусть бы даже и несколько странные(пример - юнит в игре или как создать чат). Но если 10 минут назад я размещаю тему как НЕ надо задавать вопросы, а ты тут же задаешь в таком стиле, это удивляет.

Comment: Ок.